# explanation of kindle in expression: "the risk of extinguishing the fire... by using too much kindle"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can I get an explanation of the word *kindle* in this expression:

> the risk of extinguishing the fire... by using too much kindle

Comment: Can you post the source where you found this? That could help us better determine whether this is a spelling error, a mishearing, or a very strange new usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you've misheard, or the writer has made a spelling error. [Kindle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kindle) is a verb (meaning *to start a fire*), so does not fit where you have put it. The word that should be there is [kindling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kindling), which is the material used to start a fire.

So the excerpt should read

> the risk of extinguishing the fire... by using too much kindling

Comment: Unless they're trying to burn a litter of kittens or rabbits.

Answer (score 3):

Some more context (either the source of the quotation or the preceding and following sentences) would make it easier.  But I would hazard a guess that *kindle* is used for either *tinder* or *kindling*, meaning 'small twigs, rotten wood, and similar things', used to turn a spark into a flame and a flame into a fire respectively. Over-enthusiastically adding fuel to a fire before it has properly caught is the best way to put it out.